# The random variable X follows the binomial distribution B(8,p). Given that P(X=2)=0.209, find the possible values of p.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

It says you can use a GDC. Thanks

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$nCr*(p)^r*(1-p)^{n-r}$$

$r=2$,$n=8$,$8C2=28$
We get 
$$p^2(1-p)^6=\frac{0.209}{28}$$

Take squareroot

$$p(1-p)^3=\sqrt{\frac{0.209}{28}}$$

$$p-3p^2+3p^3-p^4=\sqrt{\frac{0.209}{28}}$$

Solve this polynomial with any technique to think is easy for you

You'll get 4 values but $0<=p<=1$

So p=0.1322 or 0.4

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. The [PMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) of a binomial random variable $X\sim B(n,p)$ is
$$
f(k;n,p)\equiv\binom{n}{k}p^{k}\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}.
$$

You are given a particular binomial random variable $X\sim B(8,p)$ and are told that $f(2;8,p)=0.209$.
Can you figure out how to determine $p$ from this info?

Comment: I substituted everything I could into that equation but cannot get any forward. n would be 8 and k would be 2.

Comment: That's right. This question is a bit surprising because you end up with having to find the roots of an 8-th degree polynomial. [4 of these roots are real but only 2 of them are probabilities](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Binomial%5B8%2C2%5D*p%5E2*%281-p%29%5E6+%3D+0.209) (i.e., between zero and one). Generally, roots of higher order polynomials are obtained numerically, but it would be surprising to expect you to know how to do this if you are just learning basic probability. How did you encounter this problem?

Comment: From a question bank. It does say that you can use a graphing calculator but I have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: Use the graphing calculator to plot $f(2;8,x) - 0.209 = \binom{8}{2} x^k (1 - x)^6 - 0.209$ and see where the graph intersects the $x$ axis.